# Cloning Contactless Credit Cards

Tags: credit-card, rfid

I have the idea to inject an RFID/NFC chip in my hand and use it for payments and some other stuff.

As far as I understand, Visa Paywave is just an RFID chip with a specific ID in it, I've tried scanning my card and each time it shows the same IDs in it.

I've also tried cloning it but after cloning the POS device says that it's a faulty card.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to achieve?

Comment: If you search on this site (or Google) for "clone RFID", you will get a lot of material.

Comment: Gotta say: injecting a chip into your hand seems just a *tad* bit extreme.  Other than the health risks involved, I think you'll be very sad if you ever have to change credit cards.  I presume that if your card gets replaced (due to expiration or stolen due to factors outside your control) the RFID chip in your hand will no longer work.  Sure, maybe there are ways to fix that without a minor surgery, but there are a world of potential problems with this idea.  Simplest: what if you go somewhere that doesn't accept Visa Paywave?

Comment: @ConorMancone that's not the question. Are you aware that this practice has been around for years as a convenience for payment? It's not that extreme if you use a rice-sized, implantable chip that has been around for over a decade. And if the chip is re-writable, you can update the chip with the new data. What does it matter if a vendor does not accept Paywave?

Comment: @schroeder not that it much matters but: I presume the reason you would implant an RFID chip in your hand is so that you can pay without having to carry around a credit card.  But if there are lots of places out there (in my experience there still are) that don't accept NFC payments or the like, then you are going to end up carrying around your card anyway.  I suppose if all you want to do is to be able to wave your hand and pay, then great, but this would seem very pointless to me if I ended up still having to carry my card.

Comment: The chip is very small abd is not a health risk and can easilty be removed even at home without much blood and pain and yes, it's rewritable (you don't have to pull it out of your body to rewrite it). Lots of places accept contactless payments where I live 60-70% of all places and we even have ATM with contactless functions.

Comment: Why is this a duplicated question? Are people really that ignorant that they don't even read what the other post and this one says? The other post has almost nothin to do with this one